# OpenCL: Implementing a lookup table

Tags: c++, opencl

I am a beginner in OpenCL and am currently implementing a simple alphabetic look up table in OpenCL. The look up table is a conversion of alphabets to another. e.g. A => S, B => F, K => C.

I was given the impression that I can implement the above mentioned by using a shuffle function in my kernel, however I am stuck since there are more than alphabets than space available since I can only use up to char16 but I have 26 alphabets.

I assume I can do it in 8 char vectors {A - H}, {I - P}, but there are instances where the conversion value goes beyond the range within the same vector.

Can someone point me in the correct direction on how should I be implementing this?

Comment: Why not just make character array? `char lookup[26]`?

Comment: @ALX23z I had an initial solution that does that, but how do I implement the actual conversion? I ended up with an array of A-Z and an array of LUT but was unsure of how to continue except to check each letter one by one which of course is do-able, but I would like to use shuffle to do it if possible.

Comment: just apply `converted_value = lookup[value-'A']`. No need to use shuffle - let compiler optimize it for you (though, it might or might not).

Comment: Though, honestly, I have no idea why write it on OpenCL.